# Add new users to ICP

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I have v2.1 CE of ICP installed using Vagrant on my Macbook Pro. I would like to install a chart as a different user. Is there a way to add a new user without having to connect to LDAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in 2.1.0, you must configure LDAP (or Active Directory)